# Samba problems with virtualization

Tags: samba

I have tried ubuntu and fedora, in vmware and virtualbox and am having a consistent problem. File transfers to win7x64 (host) are full speed, but file transfers the other way, win7x64 to linux, are extremely slow which makes the entire setup unusable. There are numerous references on the net to slow samba networking with virtual machines but I can find nothing up-to-date that fixes this. I don't even know how to approach the problem. Any guidance appreciated. If you have a working system, with fast file transfers both ways, with linux in a virtual machine on a windows host, I would like to know about it. I want what you have! Otherwise I may just be wasting my time on something that will never work.

Comment: Just an idea : Try to see if that situations happens with transfers between Linux Machines and Samba and viceversa.
Doing that you'll be able to determine if it's a problem with Samba or Windows

Comment: How are you doing the copy? Are you running Samba on the guest and copying files into there with e.g. explorer from the host, or is the guest copying files onto the host server?

Comment: @jelmer Tried starting copy from both systems, both directions, same result - win7x64 to linux very slow, linux to win7x64 fast. I will try an experiment without using virtualization as time permits, I think this will be a long research project (which I don't have time for :+>

Comment: I mean, which of the two is being the server?

Comment: It doesn't matter on which of the 2 machines I start the copy, the result is the same.